# Query builder with multiselect data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I've a multiselect in a form which return an array (method=get).

In the DB I've the relative field (varchar) with stored something like:

```
["apple","lemon","banana"]
```

How to search in the DB with query builder to check if array values returned from the form are in the DB?

```
$items = Item::where(.....
```

Comment: `where('field_name', 'like', '%' . $q . '%')`

Comment: it works also with similar string like ["apple", "apple red"]?

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```
$items = Item::whereIn('name', $array)->get();
```

Comment: I think the whenIn doesn't works if the DB field contains a string like a json.